# Error in parameter estimation for Dirichlet distribution in R

Tags: r

When I use Dirichlet.mle for the following matrix it results in:

> Error in while ((conv > convcrit) & (iter < maxit)) { :
>
> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

conv seems to be NaN.

```
    A = matrix( 
            c(7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 0.9355592727661133,
 7.319874130189419E-4, 0.04137665405869484, 7.319874130189419E-4, 
7.319874130189419E-4, 0.014280209317803383, 7.319874130189419E-4, 
7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 
7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4,7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 
0.9355592727661133, 7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 
7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 0.04137665405869484, 
7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 7.319874130189419E-4, 0.014280209317803383),  
            ncol=15,             
            byrow = TRUE)

    > sirt::dirichlet.mle(A)
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Twelve of the fifteen columns in A are constant.  There's no information in your dataset about the variation in those components, so it's not surprising that the MLE calculation fails.  You need more data.

Comment: But isn't that a bug? Can't we say that when all the (very few) samples agree on a value for a column then that is the MLE for the column (according to the definition of maximum likelihood)? If yes, why should implementational details (the method used for estimation) prevent us from obtaining the MLE?

Comment: No, maximum likelihood estimates parameters, not data.  You can say with high confidence that your data did not come from a Dirichlet distribution (it wouldn't produce ties like that), so knowing which parameter values give the highest likelihood is kind of meaningless.  Perhaps that package should be able to find them, but I wouldn't blame the authors if they only wrote it to work on datasets where the distribution is really Dirichlet.